# Gem version issue when trying to install cocoapods in rubymotion

Tags: rubymotion, cocoapods

I am trying to integrate cocoapods into rubymotion according to this [tutorial](http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/articles/cocoapods/), however, when I run `rake` I got the error:

```
You have already activated i18n 0.6.5, but your Gemfile requires i18n 0.6.1. Using bundle exec may solve this.
```

What should I do, I tried specifying the gem version in the Gemfile, but it doesn't help. Here is the code in my `Rakefile`.

```
$:.unshift("/Library/RubyMotion/lib")
require 'motion/project/template/ios'
require 'rubygems'
require 'motion-cocoapods'

# if you use bundler
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require

# if you are not using bundler
# require 'rubygems'
# require 'ib'

Motion::Project::App.setup do |app|
  # Use `rake config' to see complete project settings.
  app.name = 'IBSample'

  app.pods do
    platform :ios, '6.0'
    pod 'SWRevealViewController', '~> 1.0.5'
  end
end
```

Update: Here is the gemfile

```
# A sample Gemfile
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "ib"
gem "rake"
# gem "i18n", "0.6.1"
```

When I run `bundle exec rake` , I got

```
cannot load such file -- motion-cocoapods
```

Note that I have already installed motion-cocoapods and checked that it is in my gem list.

Comment: Can you post the Gemfile too? Have you tried prefixing the command with `bundle exec`? e.g. `bundle exec rake`

Comment: @FluffyJack bundle exec gives : cannot load such file -- motion-cocoapods

Comment: Try updating your rubygems `gem update --system`. Also what version of ruby are you using?

Comment: @FluffyJack `gem update --system` doesn't fix it, I'm using `ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [x86_64-darwin13.0.0]` for this project, but I also use 2.0 with my rails

Comment: Going to replicate all this and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simply the positioning apparently.

Remove `require 'motion-cocoapods'` and put `gem motion-cocoapods` in your Gemfile, or remove the bundler code from your Rakefile and require everything manually.

```
$:.unshift("/Library/RubyMotion/lib")
require 'motion/project/template/ios'
require 'rubygems'

require 'ib'
require 'motion-cocoapods'

Motion::Project::App.setup do |app|
  # Use `rake config' to see complete project settings.
  app.name = 'IBSample'

  app.pods do
    platform :ios, '6.0'
    pod 'SWRevealViewController', '~> 1.0.5'
  end
end
```

Though I then got an error because of `platform` in the pods definition, but you can likely remove it unless you really need it, then that's your next problem :)